# Text position in Matplotlib with absolute x coordinate, but not y

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to place text on a plot with matplotlib. I want the x coordinate of the text to be set at a value, but I want the y coordinate of the text to be at the 'top' of the plot.

Currently, I am using the y_lim of the axes to place the text, however if someone moves scales or pans the graph, the text will move.

```
x_pos = 300 # For example
y_pos = 0.95*axs.get_ylim()[1]
axs.text(x_pos, y_pos, text)
```

Using:

```
axs.text(0, 1, text,transform = axs.transAxes)
```

Would place the text in the top corner, and the text wouldn't move during scaling and panning, but it doesn't allow the specification of an x-coordinate.

I want the text to be able to move along the x-axis when scaling and panning the graph, but to always be fixed in the y-axis

Is there anyway to achieve this with matplotlib.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please see blended transforms in the transforms tutorial. https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations

Comment: Thanks Jody, this was perfect! Can you convert your comment to answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: There are two special blended transforms already precooked: ax.get_xaxis_transform() and ax.get_yaxis_transform()